# Incrementally scaling an object on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, scale

I'm trying to make a div grow with every click. Not sure on how to incorporate a transformation within a for loop.

**JavaScript**

```
$(function(){
  $("#heart").click(function(){$(this).toggleClass("active")})
})
```

**CSS**

```
div {
 transition: all 2s ease-out;
}

div.active {
 transform: scale(2,2);
}
```

This is essentially all I have at the moment since I have no idea how a loop works.

Comment: can you show us what have you done so far?

Comment: can you post it in your question.. and also add the relevent html code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you already tried yourself to do this? Please review [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). Stack Overflow is not a coding service. You are expected to research your issue and make a good attempt to write the code yourself before posting. If you get stuck on something specific, come back and include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and a summary of what you tried, so we can help.

Comment: Stop thinking 'loop', you don't need one, just a click handler.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you using `ES6 template literals` https://jsfiddle.net/ym4Lwrr0/

```js
$(function(){
  var i = 1;
  $("#heart").click(function(){
    i++;
    $(this).css({
     transform: `scale(${i},${i})`
    });
  })
})
```

```css
div {
 transition: all 2s ease-out;
 border: 1px solid red;
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 5px;
 transform: scale(1,1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="heart">
 test
</div>
```

For old browser where `ES6 template literals` doesn't support, here is the solution https://jsfiddle.net/ym4Lwrr0/1/

```js
$(function(){
 var i = 1;
  $("#heart").click(function(){
   i++;
    var scaleValue = "scale(" + i + "," + i + ")"

   $(this).css({
     transform: scaleValue
    });
  })
})
```

```css
div {
 transition: all 2s ease-out;
 border: 1px solid red;
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 5px;
 transform: scale(1,1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="heart">
 test
</div>
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: `scale(${i},${i})` Worth noting that these are template literals which is an ES6 feature so it might not work in some older browsers.